# Get items of multiple arrays with async

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, async.js

I'm using [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html) in my Node.js application and I don't understand how can I pass multiple arrays to `async.each()` in parameter and get the good current item. Actually I do this but this is not the good way.

```
var data = [];
var counter = 0;

var arrayOne   = ['1', '2', '3'];
var arrayTwo   = ['4', '5', '6'];
var arrayThree = ['7', '8', '9'];
var arrayFour  = ['10', '11', '12'];

async.each(arrayOne, function (item, next){
    data.push({
        'One'   : item,
        'Two'   : arrayTwo[counter],
        'Three' : arrayThree[counter],
        'Four'  : arrayFour[counter],
    });
});
```

I give arrayOne to `async.each` and I can get the current item in parameter, then I can use `item` to add it in my array. But for the other arrays I have to use a counter variable.

I would like something like this but I don't know if it's possible :

```
async.each([arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, arrayFour], function (item1, item2, item3, item4, next){
    data.push({
        'One'   : item1,
        'Two'   : item2,
        'Three' : item3,
        'Four'  : item4,
    });
});
```

There is a way to send all my arrays and get the current item of each array ?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using async? What is the async here?

Comment: This code in my question is just an example of my code. I'll not paste all my code. I'm using async because I have more than 1 000 000 data to parse and I have to do this with async.

Comment: Is there any valid reason to use async? Besides, you technically can pass an array containing the four arrays as the first parameter, but I still miss the logic about how data["One"] is meant to be from arrayOne, there are no key/value sets to make it automatic. What is the expected result? you likely need a nested each anyway.

Comment: @briosheje I have lot of data in my loop. I already tried with a simple `for` loop and I noticed that it takes 650ms and with `async.each` it takes just 150ms. But if you have another solution you can paste an answer.

Comment: @John: This is the best I could think to make it logically more correct: https://jsfiddle.net/43gjonz6/ . It doesn't even rely on the async library but is async (test it, it is async). I think you should add some logic to your script, else it's quite hard to properly help you.

Comment: I think your solution is nice and elegant, so I think you should leave it like this...

Comment: @briosheje I did some test in my code. You're right I made a mistake I will not use async for this. I thought async was faster than my `for` loop. Yes it's faster but I tried with a basic `forEach` and I have the save ms. And I tried with `map`I got better performance. I can get 50ms with `map` and 150ms with `forEach`.

Comment: @John: If the problem is performance-related, you should rather think about spawning a separate thread to handle calculations instead ;) using async is necessary to don't freeze the process / the view. If you need to do heavy calculations and you need to update a view, you would better handle calculations on another thread (or a task, or a worker.. whatever) and update the view through an I/O channel.

Comment: @briosheje I don't have any view here. It's purely backend. Parse data / Add to mongoDb... But I have a rest API on the same node server. I used `async.parallel`  to downloading some file. It works fine. But when I'm in the huge loop to map my array, all client (who calling API) will waiting for the end of the loop. It's normal ? Should I implement something like beanstalkd ?

Comment: If you're about to have a long task running background (anyway, isn't mongodb async already?..), you should either plan a progressbar on the client side or just give them something entertaining to do meanwhile, like starring at a funny loading icon or whatever. A progressbar or something similar should be enough anyway, perhaps you can define some steps (contacting server, adding data, data added, collecting results). It also depends how heavy the data adding process is. Keep in mind that you should remove any console.log if the process is extremely long and repetitive.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. The process isn't too long. It will takes 10-20seconds once a day.